# SharePoint Name to Number

Tags: sharepoint-2010

I am trying to convert a name in a list to number I have a column with the title Name and it contains multiple name and I want to create a column which will take the name in the name column and change it to number, this formula works `=IF(Name="Jhon","2")` if I want to add more names, numbers it wont work for example, my formula is as follows.

```
=IF(Name ="Jhon","2")
=IF(Name ="Mike","1") 
=IF(Name ="Jane","3")
```

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The formula should be like this:

```
=IF(Name ="Jhon","2", IF(Name ="Mike","1",IF(Name ="Jane","3")))
```

For more, you could refer to this article:

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/if-function-7025be14-5665-43d0-af20-8293d1fe9d3a

Comment: Thanks, I was sure I tried that prior, its now working.